# 3NF Normal form

Tags: normalization

I have a question about 3NF normal form:

```
Normalize, with respect to 3NF, the relational scheme E(A, B, C, D, E, F) 
by assuming that (A, B, C) is the unique candidate key and that the following additional functional dependencies hold: 
    A,B -> D 
    C,D -> E 
    E -> F
```

My understanding is that if I apply the 3NF which says that a schema is 3NF if all attributes

non-prime do not transitively depend on any key candidate , the result should be:

E'=(A,B,C,E,F), E''= (B,D) , E'''= A,B,C,D,F) , E''''=(D,E) , E''''''= (A,B,C,D,E),

E''''''= (E,F)

but I do think I'm wrong...

Can someone help understand the issue?

Thanks

Comment: Is this homework? That's a tag for that.

Comment: " . . . 3NF which says that a schema is 3NF if all attributes non-prime do not transitively depend on any key candidate" No. 3NF means that a) the relation is in 2NF, and b) every non-prime attribute is directly dependent (that is, not transitively dependent) on *every* candidate key.

Answer (score 1):

(Reformatted for readability)

> My understanding is that if I apply the 3NF which says that a schema
>   is 3NF if all attributes  non-prime do not transitively depend on any
>   key candidate , the result should be:
>
> - E<sup>1</sup>= {A,B,C,E,F}
> - E<sup>2</sup>= {B,D}
> - E<sup>3</sup>= {A,B,C,D,F}
> - E<sup>4</sup>= {D,E}
> - E<sup>5</sup>= {A,B,C,D,E}
> - E<sup>6</sup>= {E,F}

3NF means that a) the relation is in 2NF, and b) every non-prime attribute is directly dependent (that is, not transitively dependent) on *every* candidate key.

In turn, 2NF means that a) the relation is in 1NF, and b) every non-prime attribute is dependent on the whole of every candidate key, not just on part of any candidate key.

Given {ABC} is a candidate key, and given {AB->D}, you can see that D depends on part of a candidate key. So

- E<sup>0</sup> = {A,B,C,D,E,F}

is not in 2NF. You fix that by moving that dependent attribute to a new relation, and you copy the attributes that determine it to the same relation.

- R<sup>0</sup> = {**ABC** DEF} This relation—which we started with, and which is not in 2NF—goes away, to be replaced with
- R<sup>1</sup> = {**ABC** EF}
- R<sup>2</sup> = {**AB** D}

You want to continue from here?

Comment: thanks Catcall ..I think if I have carry on I have to write : R3(ABCDF) , R4(CDE),R5(ABCDE), R6(EF)..am I right?..That means the relation I started with is now normalized ..The key thing is to check if R is in 2NF and then start with normalization..is that correct?

Comment: @user962800: How did you derive "R3(ABCDF)"?

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to getting normalization right, there is no substitute for understanding the formal definitions.  If you're still working on building that understanding, there's a cute little mnemonic that people use to help remember the essence of 3NF and to judge whether a table that they're looking at is 3NF or not.

> "The key, the whole key, and nothing but the key, so help me [Codd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.F._Codd)."

How do you apply it?  Every attribute of the relation must depend on the key.  It must depend on the *whole* key.  I must not depend on anything that *isn't* the key.  When you look at your example, clearly there are problems and you need to normalize.  You need to get to a point where every non-key column which violates 3NF is out of your original relation.  Each of the non-key columns, D, E, and F all violate 3NF.

Note that your additional functional dependencies cover all of the non-key columns in your original relation.  Each of these additional functional dependencies is going to result in a relation:

{ **A B** D } - This solves 3NF for attribute D
{ **C D** E } - This solves 3NF for attribute E
{ **E** F } - This solves 3NF for attribute F

What is left to cover from your original relation?  Nothing except the candidate key:

{ **A B C** }

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply..I think I grasped the gist ..Do you think I can find exercises about Normalization ?..thanks

Comment: No problem!  Feel free to upvote the answer if you like it.  I'm sure there are lots of normalization exercises.  Try looking in Google for database+normalization+exercises.

Comment: "The key, the whole key..." mnemonic is fundamentally inaccurate. Normalization is equally concerned with ALL candidate keys and not just any one key per table. So it's not enough to say "the key" as though there is just one key to be considered. That's why I'd rather not see that particular mnemonic repeated without further clarifications.

Comment: You will note that I started my answer with "When it comes to getting normalization right, there is no substitute for understanding the formal definitions...".  In my experience, many programmers have more than a little difficulty getting past the mathematical theory and so they struggle with being able to recognize when any given table is 3NF or not.  The mnemonic is a simplification - obviously.  Since it says "the key" it would be a matter for English.StackExchange.com as to whether the mnemonic is lax, incorrect, or silent on the matter of candidate versus primary keys.